# Disable 'Prices' appearing in Magento

Tags: magento

How do I disable ALL Prices being shown on the public end of Magento?

I basically want to allow my customer to add products to their cart but for the item prices/totals etc to be invisible.

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either remove the template code which renders the price or simply add a css class and hide it using styling!

You should do that in your catalog/navigation, catalog/product/view, checkout/cart, sales/order/view, in checkout/review, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Hide price-box class from css it will help you

Answer (score 1):

A css (partial ?) solution to play around:

```
.price-box .price{
    display: none;
}
.price-box:after {
    content: '-'; /*contact us for price*/
}
.cart-price .price {
    display: none;
}
.cart-price:after {
    content: '-';
}
.cart-table-totals {
    display: none;
}
label[for=s_method_flatrate_flatrate] {
    display: none;
}
#checkout-review-table tfoot {
    display: none;
}
#shipping_method-progress-opcheckout .price {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT here is a free module that will do this for you:** http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/red2black-hideprices.html

I am not sure how advanced or not you are but this could be done as a module. You would add an attribute to the product, and based on whether it is true or no you would hide the pricing in the relevant templates.

Here is a detailed thread on how to do this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22673/

If you are in the mood to spend a few $$ you could buy this module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bolasevich/extension/2096/hide-product-price-for-non-registered-users

Or if you are in the mood to spend tons of money you could buy this one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Cart2Quote/extension/5905/not2order_hide_price_disable_ordering

Answer (score 0):

This post was very useful for me:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/87901/

hiding price:

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

insert at the very beggining of the file:

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
```

insert at the very end of the file

```
<?php } ?>
```